# How to put an icon on the iPhone lock screen?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not certain what OS made this capability available but I noticed that on my iPhone 5 (which is running the beta iOS8), when the phone is locked a "W" icon was appearing at the bottom-left. It shows "Slide to Unlock", the camera icon on the right, the "bar" that lets me access the control center in the middle - and a "W" on the left. Sliding this "W" up launches the Walgreen's iPhone app. I do not think this is a normal UINotification, nothing in Passbook, and when I go into the Notification Center settings, turning all notifications off for the Walgreen app, the icon still shows.

Is this a notification? Is this a plist parameter? Bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Why a -1? At least comment. http://appadvice.com/appnn/2014/06/apples-ios-8-provides-quick-location-based-access-to-apps-from-the-lock-screen

Comment: @Larme "How do I program my app to support this" is pretty common around here.

Comment: I believe this is part of the new iOS 8 extensions capabilities.  Grab the WWDC videos and do some research on Extensions.

Comment: Cruel Internet. Love how no one realizes I posted the "possible reason" with not real evidence other than theory - from anyone. I now have the AppStore forcing itself on my on the lock screen. I think the capability is relevant for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new ios 8 feature that displays an app (purchased or not) that is relevant to your location.  You must have been near a Walgreens at the time.  As far as I know, there is no way to choose that app or submit an app for that.  Apple decides what displays there.

Comment: FYI - was no where near a Walgreens. I also installed other apps, such as Starbucks, rumored to be in the same "market" and never saw a Starbucks icon even when in the store. People often assume the person that asked the question did no research before asking. I'll have to make certain I list the 300 other web searches, sample applications, Apple developer notes, etc. that I researched before deciding to ask a question If the answer was simple, I would not have asked.

Comment: I do agree that Apple has "sneaked" this in as my new icon has been the AppStore more often now - but for no good reason. I'm never "near" an AppStore. There must be more behind the API that will become obvious as iOS-8 matures.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn this off by going to settings > General > Handoff and Suggested Apps. Then turn off Installed Apps. According to the description, these Apps are suggested based on usage and location.